# Optimizing this matrix shifter

Tags: c++, optimization, matrix

I need to optimize this piece of code I made because this will run in real-time mode.

It's a matrix shifter that pulls downward and will neglect any transparent element.

**Code:**

```
void shiftDown(int col)
{
    int x = 0;  //transparent element
    int N = 5;  //size
    int i,j,k,l;

    for ( i = N - 1;i >= 0; --i )
    {
        if( map[i][col] == x )
        {
            for( j = i;j >= 0; --j )
            {
                if ( map[j][col] != x )
                {
                    for ( l = i, k = j;l >= 0; --l, --k )
                    {
                        map[l][col] = map[k][col];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Data:**

(*before*)

```
0 2 3 2 0
0 1 4 0 1
1 2 2 0 3
2 1 0 0 4
4 3 1 1 3
```

(*after*)

```
0 2 0 0 0
0 1 3 0 1
1 2 4 0 3
2 1 2 2 4
4 3 1 1 3
    ^ ^
```

**Other code**

```
int map[][5] =
{
  {0, 2, 3, 2, 0},
  {0, 1, 4, 0, 1},
  {1, 2, 2, 0, 3},
  {2, 1, 0, 0, 4},
  {4, 3, 1, 1, 3}
};

void printMap();
void shiftDown(int col);

int main()
{
    cout << "before\n";
    printMap();

    for (int i = 0;i < 5; ++i)
    {
        shiftDown(i);
    }
    cout << "after\n";
    printMap();


    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void printMap()
{
    for (int row = 0;row < 5; ++row)
    {
        for (int col = 0;col < 5; ++col)
        {
            cout << map[row][col] << '\t';
        }
        cout << endl << endl << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

**Note:** Looked at my comment again and I need to correct my error. Its `int map[N][N]` again. This will not work for M x N matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort each column separately (only move the transparent value to the top of the column) with a fast sorting algorithm like merge sort:

```
void mergeSortBlock(int *a, int index1, int index2, int size, int transparent){
    int *result;
    int resultIndex = 0;
    int mergeIndex1 = index1;
    int mergeIndex2 = index2;

    result = new int [size*2];

    while (mergeIndex1 <= (index1 + size -1) && mergeIndex2 <= (index2 + size -1)){
        if (a[mergeIndex2] == transparent) {  // check the transparency
            result[resultIndex] = a[mergeIndex2];
            resultIndex++;
            mergeIndex2++;
        }
        else {
            result[resultIndex] = a[mergeIndex1];
            resultIndex++;
            mergeIndex1++;
        }
    }

    if (mergeIndex2 <= (index2 + size - 1)) {
        for (int i = mergeIndex2 ; i< (index2 + size); i++) {
            result[resultIndex] = a[mergeIndex2];
            resultIndex++;
            mergeIndex2++;              
        }
    }
    else{
        for (int i = mergeIndex1 ; i< (index1 + size); i++) {
            result[resultIndex] = a[mergeIndex1];
            resultIndex++;
            mergeIndex1++;
        }
    }

    // copy the result back
    for (int i=0; i < size*2; i++) {
        a[index1+i] = result[i];
    }       
    delete [] result;
}

void mergeSort(int *a, int indexFront,int indexEnd, int transparent){
    int size = (indexEnd - indexFront +1)/2;
    if (size > 1){
        mergeSort(a, indexFront, indexFront + size - 1, transparent); 
        mergeSort(a, indexFront + size, indexEnd, transparent);
    }
    mergeSortBlock(a, indexFront, indexFront + size, size, transparent);
}
```

As you can see, in the **mergeSortBlock** function, instead of examining `a[mergeIndex1]>a[mergeIndex2]` you check the **transparency** condition.

the **indexFront** is the index of the first element of your array and **indexEnd** is the index of the last element.

Now in your main, first you need to transpose the matrix so that the *ith* row of the transposed matrix (called **result** in this example) represents the *ith* column of your **map** matrix. then call the **mergeSort** function for each row of the transposed matrix, **Result** .

```
int  main()
    int result[5][5];
    int map[][5] =
    {
        {0, 2, 3, 2, 0},
        {0, 1, 4, 0, 1},
        {1, 2, 2, 0, 3},
        {2, 1, 0, 0, 4},
        {4, 3, 1, 1, 3}
    };

    //transpose map => map's ith column = result's ith row
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
            result[j][i] = map[i][j];


    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) 
        mergeSort(result[i],0,4,0);


    //transpose reuslt => result's ith row = map's ith column
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
            map[j][i] = result[i][j];

    return 0;
}
```

At the end again we need to transpose the matrix **result**.

Note: The complexity of merge sort is O(n.logn). You have n columns. This makes the complexity of the matrix shifter O(n^2.logn). Thanks to the nature of your problem, you can still improve this by parallel programming (of course if you have multiple processors). The complexity of transpose is O(n^2). The complexity of your own algorithm is O(n^3).

Note2: You can modify **mergeSort** and **mergeSortBlock** functions to work directly with the columns of your matrix.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but that would alter all its content.  I need to preserved their order. Only the `transparent` element are needed to move up.

Comment: @mr5: I know. You can still do it. check the answer. Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: I haven't tested this entire thing yet, but it looks like you should still consider an `std::vector` to avoid the `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @Jamal: Yes, you can use `std::vector`. You can also use smart pointers like `std::auto_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr` but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Right, but it could help with optimization.

Comment: @Jamal: I don't think so :-)

Comment: Eh, well, I suppose it comes down to whether or not the OP can use the STL.  It's your answer.

Comment: @NejlaGhaboosi Uhmm, your code kinda alter all the columns position of the matrix. The logic is that pull down all `non-transparent` element on every column preserving their order. See the output [here](http://ideone.com/kRsDi7) or I think I don't get it right. Also the size of the matrix should be N x N (2 dimensional) and `5` != N x N.

Comment: @mr5 No you didn't get it right and what is 5? I didn't get it. What I wrote above was a one dimensional array (just an example to show you how you can call the function). anyway, I write your full code tomorrow.

Comment: you can also use openMP in order to do it :)